# AWS Lambda function timing out on calling aws service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function which has the following logic in the handler:

```
    log.info("about to get caller identity..")
    caller_identity = boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity()
    log.info(caller_identity)
```

When I run this lambda function, it times out with the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://sts.amazonaws.com/"
```

Why is my lambda function not able to reach STS service?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Lambda associated with a VPC?

Comment: Yes - it is! Thank you for that hint.. It is part of a VPC and is in a private subnet! That was  the issue.. I reconfigued it so that all traffic for the lambda goes through a proxy which sits in the same VPC but in a public subnet  - it works now. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This was the result of the Lambda being associated to a VPC in a private subnet with no way to communicate to the internet.

It is important that when using VPC configuration the Lambda is located in a subnet with the means to communicate with the internet such as a NAT. Without this your Lambda cannot communicate to the internet.

If you're trying to reach an AWS service you can check whether a [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) is supported for the service to remove the need for internet connectivity.